# React Router: Transition without window.location

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have an application that uses React Router. The application creates a new item by calling the `createPage` action, which calls my RefluxJS store and makes a call to an API endpoint. Once that API call returns and is successful I pass the new `page` object to the `pageCreated` action. Within my `onChanged` even in the JSX file I want to transition to a route based on a property of the `page` without refreshing the page, but I am at a loss on how to do it.

I want to do something similar to `window.location = /pages/1234` where 1234 comes from the `page` object returned by the API.

I have tried `Router.transitionTo('/ua-manager/pages/' + options.alias);`, but that returns as not a function. How can I achieve this transition without using `window.location`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#transitionTo` exists on the Router object instance and not the class so access it through `this.context.router` and it'll work or just add the `Navigation` mixin.

```
this.context.router.transitionTo('/ua-manager/pages' + options.alias);
```

Comment: Just because it may not be 100% clear you can use this.transitionTo without the context part as long as you use the Navigation mixin

Comment: Yep, absolutely correct. Clarified a bit in my answer, thanks!